# How to create pdf of elements displayed in container through code in flex in a desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, adobe

I have a border container having some controls. I want to create pdf document of elemts displayed in container upon a button click. How can i do this? Please help

Comment: This link helped                                 http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/wp-content/tutorials/alivepdf-tutorial-getting-started.swf

Answer (score 0):

you can generate PDF using the PurePDF opensource ActionScript Library. [Click here for PurePDF Source](http://code.google.com/p/purepdf/)

you will find out the example also.